# How to add equal space between inline block elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't want to auto fill space with blocks content. I want equal spacing between fixed-width blocks, that would also be flexible.

I can do that by adding `padding-right: whatever;` and then adding another `padding-right: 0;` to `.last` block, but that's very primitive and not mobile friendly.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/9twy5drd/1/

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.container .block {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container2 {
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container2 .block {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 47px 0 0;
}
.container2 .block.last {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
</div>

<p>What we want, but not with fixed method:</p>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block last">Some block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just wondering, is there a specific reason you're using `inline-block` elements? What part of their behaviour is desirable for your purposes?

Comment: Also, what problem are you trying to solve with this layout? It seems like a grid system, media queries or flexbox might be your solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `Flexbox` and `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.container .block {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
</div>
```

Here is js solution for older browsers that don't support `Flexbox`. I calculated `margin-left` for each `block` element to create equal spacing between elements. Also white space from HTML must be removed.

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  var block = $('.container > .block');
  var count = block.length;
  var bWidth = block.outerWidth();
  var pWidth = $('.container').innerWidth();

  var margin = (pWidth - (bWidth * count)) / (count - 1);

  if (margin > 0) block.not(':last').css('margin-right', margin);
}).resize();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.container .block {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Some block</div><div class="block">Some block</div><div class="block">Some block</div><div class="block">Some block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but IE11 only. The other solution posted works on older browsers, but not Safari and this works on very new versions only. Need compromise.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but i think js is only other solution then.

Comment: @user13176 I added js solution that could help you.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `justify` your container and don't forget to use `text-align-last` (Firefox 49 and newer will not need prefix)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container .block {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
  <div class="block">Some block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, but not supported on Safari.