# Why are margins not consistent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, margin

I have set the margin of my child divs to 40px, yet the distance between the parent container and first div is less that the distance  between first and second div. Furthermore, there is difference of 1-2 between the rest of gaps. You can crosscheck by inserting two adjacent element's index in place of existing indexes at rows 9 and 10 of my JavaScript code. For instance: The gap between first and second element is 105px, between 2nd and 3rd it's 104px, between 3rd and 4th it is 106px, and between 4th and 5th it is back to 104px. These all should've been 40px (80px i guess as i just checked margin don't collapse horizontally). Am i missing something very basic? [I'm trying to make an image slider. Files](https://yogeshsportfolio.com/)

```js
let projectContainer = document.querySelector(".project-container")
let projects = document.querySelectorAll(".project")

let initialPosition = 0;
let mouseIsDown = false
let distanceTravelled = 0;

elementAOffset = projects[3].offsetLeft;
elementBOffset = projects[4].offsetLeft;
elementAWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(projects[0]).width)
margin = (elementBOffset - (elementAOffset + elementAWidth))

var LeftSideBoundary = -1 * ((elementAWidth * 2) + (margin))
var RightSideBoundary = (elementAWidth * 6) + (margin * 5) + elementAOffset
var RightSidePosition = RightSideBoundary - elementAWidth;

projectContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    mouseIsDown = true
    initialPosition = e.clientX;
    console.log("Mouse key pressed")
})

projectContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
    mouseExit(e)
})

projectContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", e => {
    mouseExit(e);
})


projectContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
    if (!mouseIsDown) { return };
    projects.forEach(project => {
        project.style.transform = 'translateX(' + ((e.clientX - initialPosition) + project.currentTranslationX ?? 0) + 'px)'
        shiftPosition(e, project)
    })
})




function mouseExit(e) {
    mouseIsDown = false

    distanceTravelled = e.clientX - initialPosition

    var example_project = projects[0]
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(example_project)
    currentTranslationX = (new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform)).m41


    projects.forEach(project => {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(project)
        project.currentTranslationX = (new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform)).m41

        project.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (project.currentTranslationX ?? 0) + 'px)'

    })
}


function shiftPosition(e, project) {
    animationShift = window.getComputedStyle(project)
    animationShift = (new WebKitCSSMatrix(animationShift.webkitTransform)).m41
    animationShift = animationShift + project.offsetLeft

    if (animationShift <= LeftSideBoundary) {
        project.style.transform = "translateX(" + (RightSidePosition - project.offsetLeft) + "px)"
    }
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size:100px;
    user-select: none;
}

.project-container{
    width:1500px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: rgb(15, 207, 224);
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:60px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.project{
    margin:40px 40px 40px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    height:300px;
    width:350px;
    background-color:white;
    border: black 3px solid;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="project-container">
        <div class="project">1</div>
        <div class="project">2</div>
        <div class="project">3</div>
        <div class="project">4</div>
        <div class="project">5</div>
        <div class="project">6</div>
        <div class="project">7</div>
        <div class="project">8</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Its the extra space to meet the 400px CSS rule you added to the `project-container`

Comment: any idea how i can make the gaps equal? And on what basis is this space calculated? I already have more items that what the container can fit, the items are overflowing

Comment: You've set the width & height to 1500 x 400px so that's why they are "overflowing" and have uneven space at the bottom. Why are you using translate for the boxes? They are just regular boxes so why not just use positioning? If you are trying to do something else, you need to tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve because otherwise we don't know what we are trying to fix.

Comment: So i am trying to make an image slider. Your drag and the divs move and then loop infinitely. This only works for one side currently. I dont have issue with vertical space. I don't understand why they have uneven space between them (horizontally). As per my understanding: If the parent  had more space, they would be 80px apart and there would be more space remaining at the end. In this case, the space should be 80px between the divs and the overflowing content should be hidden (which it is unless you drag), but why this random 105px, 106px unconsistent space. thanks.files yogeshsportfolio.com/

Comment: OK, but I still don't understand why you are using `translate`? That's obviously where the problem is happening. Can you not use CSS positioning and change the order?

Comment: All this time, i've just been watching tutorials. I recently started making projects. I don't know he best practices and ways. I'll definitely give positioning a try. I tried working with nodeChilds previously but that isn't working (my previous or the one before it question). But here javascript is not doing anything until i drag within the container, so i doubt translate is causing issues

Comment: so i figured it out, it's the space between divs in html. got this resolved by setting font-size to zero.

Comment: I can't believe you just worked that out now... I've just been working on an answer right now also to say the same! But I'm using flexbox which is considered a better approach these days :)

Comment: thank you very much. I'll definitely try this with flexbox as well

Comment: You can see it working below... the reason it took so long was trying to work out how to stop the boxes resizing (take out the `flex:none` line and you'll see what it does), and I had just figured it out! Take a look at it as its the recommended way nowadays, but the important thing is that you have something that works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using `inline-block`, which uses inline display and this means *all* the content is displayed inline - even white space. What you are seeing is the white space that is in your HTML between the `</div>` of one block and the `<div>` of the next.

There have been [various workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455445/how-to-add-equal-space-between-inline-block-elements), for example, removing the space between the elements, e.g.

```
<div class="project">1</div><div class="project">2</div><div class="project">3</div>...etc
```

However, these days the best way is to use the flexbox layout.

- Use `display:flex` in the container
- **This is the important part for your example**: `flex: none;` for the boxes inside that container (otherwise they will get resized to fit into the display area, regardless of what width you have given them in the CSS)

The CSS you need to add is:

```
.project-container{
    display: flex;
    /* rest of your CSS */
}

.project{
    flex: none;
    /* rest of your CSS */
}
```

Working Snippet (note: I've removed the margins so you can see it more clearly):

```css
*, *::before, *::after{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size:100px;
    user-select: none;
}

.project-container{
    display: flex;
    width:1500px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: rgb(15, 207, 224);
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:60px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.project{
    flex: none;
    margin:40px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height:300px;
    width:350px;
    background-color:white;
    border: black 3px solid;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-container">
        <div class="project">1</div>
        <div class="project">2</div>
        <div class="project">3</div>
        <div class="project">4</div>
        <div class="project">5</div>
        <div class="project">6</div>
        <div class="project">7</div>
        <div class="project">8</div>
    </div>
```